# Show a, b and c are coplanar

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

A plane contains the non-zero, non-parallel vectors **a** and **b**, and has normal vector **n**. If **c** is any vector which is perpendicular to n, show that **a**, **b** and **c** are coplanar.

How would I go about showing this without having any position vectors?

Comment: Out of curiosity what method are you referring to when you say "rather than integers"?

Comment: Also to clarify, these vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ right?

Comment: I meant without position vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that

$$\vec a \times \vec b = k\vec n$$

let $\vec c$ such that $\vec c \cdot \vec n =0$ than

$$\vec c \cdot \vec n=\vec c \cdot (\vec a \times \vec b)=0$$

and since the [**triple product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) is equal to zero, we have that $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ are coplanars.

Comment: OP hasn't yet clarified if this is necessary, but does this work in, say, $\mathbb{R}^4$? Or be generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @79037662 I'm assuming $a,b,c \in \mathbb R^3$. Otherwise it is not true in general.

Comment: @79037662 If this is in a higher-dimensional space than $\mathbb R^3$, then you can’t talk about a plane’s normal vector in the first place.